# TYPO3 tutorial extension, controller does not exist

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm trying to get started with TYPO3 extensions and was following [this](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/7-configuring-the-plugin.html) tutorial to get to see the basics.

In the backend everything works fine, but on the front end I get an error:

> Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20170209104827c3b58d58 -
>   {"exception":"exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class
>   Tx_Inventory_Controller_InventoryController does not exist'

My files are exactly the same as in the tutorial. I have no idea what is causing this. I assume I made some dumb mistake with namespaces, but they seem to be all correct.

The controller class can be found below and is located in **typo3conf/ext/inventory/Classes/Controller/**

```
<?php
   namespace \MyVendor\Inventory\Controller;
   use \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
   use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
   use \MyVendor\Inventory\Domain\Model\Repository\ProductRepository;

   class InventoryController extends ActionController {
        public function listAction() {
                $productRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ProductRepository::class)
                $products = $productRepository->findAll();
                $this->view->assign('products', $products);
        }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Please post the top of your Controller file typo3conf/ext/inventory/Classes/Controller/InventoryController.php? Maybe you have wrong syntax in namespace or classname. Ensure, you have loaded your classes, which are not automaticly loaded, if you just create/upload it. Best would be, to deinstall/reinstall your EXT:inventory if you add new PHP class files.

Comment: Thanks of the reply! I added it to the post.

Answer (score 10):

When developing a new extension in a composer installed TYPO3 V9 (here: 9.4) the autoload part has to be added to the central root composer.json. Found it [here (German)](https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/126840/). Following the steps in the [OPs mentioned tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/Index.html) leads to a core exception:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1278450972:
  Class MyVendor\StoreInventory\Controller\StoreInventoryController does not exist.
  Reflection failed.
```

As long as the extension is not installed via composer, e.g because it's newly developed, composer does not find the appropriate `composer.json` file in the extensions directory. Hence TYPO3 does not find any classes in the new extensions `Classes` directory. To resolve the issue the autoload configuration has to be added to the root `composer.json`. Just put the following lines into `composer.json` within the installations base directory:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
    ],
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyVendor\\StoreInventory\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/store_inventory/Classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

Then regenerate the autoload configuration:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

You possibly have to clear the cache as well in the backend.

Comment: thanks a million! Your answer saved me now already the 2nd time!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your class is not autoloaded. If you don't use composer to make your autoload, take a look in your typo3conf/autoload/autoload_classmap.php file.

You should find an entry corresponding to your file. You will see if you have a path error.

Answer (score 3):

Remove backslashes - try with

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\Inventory\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use MyVendor\Inventory\Domain\Model\Repository\ProductRepository;

class InventoryController extends ActionController {

    public function listAction() {
            $productRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ProductRepository::class)
            $products = $productRepository->findAll();
            $this->view->assign('products', $products);
    }
}
```

Ensure you add Vendorname to extension key, when you register your plugin, see ext_tables.php and write *'MyVendor.'.$_EXTKEY* instead of *$_EXTKEY* like

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'MyVendor.'.$_EXTKEY,
    'List',
    'The Inventory List'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. I have the feeling the controller is ok, but Typo3 is looking in the wrong place. Also the error says Class Tx_Inventory_Controller_InventoryController, which is the old way of naming classes, right?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version?

Comment: TYPO3 Version 7.6.15

Comment: I see a minor mistake in the documentation you linked. Change $_EXTKEY in ext_tables.php, where you register your plugin. For "\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin($_EXTKEY,..." write "\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin('MyVendor.inventory',..."

Comment: Was two mistakes you need to correct in your syntax - as written/edited in my answer

Comment: Do not replace `$_EXTKEY`. It will create all sorts of problems if you set this to a fixed string, especially in composer mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - it happens if Typo3 installation is done by composer. To solve this problem [see this page of the docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/MigrateToComposer/BestPractices.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add autoload in your ext_emconf.php (replace 'Vendor\\Extensionkey\\') and uninstall and install your extension again (to rebuild PHP autoload information)

```
  'autoload' =>
    array (
        'psr-4' =>
            array (
                'Vendor\\Extensionkey\\' => 'Classes',
            ),
    ),
    '_md5_values_when_last_written' => 'a:0:{}',
    'suggests' => array(
),
```