# TYPO3 Controller Class could not be found. Where do I link it?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am developing an extension for TYPO3 v9.5.9, and have written all of my code, however when I try using the extension I get an error message saying

> Class Secsign\Secsign\Controller\SecsignController does not exist.
>   Reflection failed.

[image]

```
<?php
namespace Secsign\Secsign\Controller;

$apiPath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('secsign') . 'Resources/Public/SecSignIDApi/phpApi/SecSignIDApi.php';
require_once($apiPath);

use AuthSession;
use SecSignIDApi;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;


/**
 * SecsignController
 */
class SecsignController extends ActionController
{...}
```

The controller does exist, but for some reason it can't be found. Where does this error occur? How do I fix it? Any hints are welcome.

The composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "secsign/secsign",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "This extension allows users to authenticate using their smart phone running the SecSign App.",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "SecSign Technologies Inc.",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": "^9.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Secsign\\Secsign\\": "Classes",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Secsign\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/secsign/Classes/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Secsign\\Secsign\\Tests\\": "Tests"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "secsign/secsign": "self.version",
        "typo3-ter/secsign": "self.version"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried flushing system cache and rebuild PHP autoload Information?

Comment: Yes I have tried that multiple times already. No luck.

Comment: Try removing backslashes from the namespace. See the @jokumer's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133409/typo3-tutorial-extension-controller-does-not-exist)

Comment: 1) a `use` statement with a leading backslash is not recommended (but should work anyway)
2) how does your composer.json look like?

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava would I have to do that in every single class I have?

Comment: @Wolfgang I added the composer.json to the question description!

Comment: there you have your answer. `"TYPO3\\CMS\\Secsign\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/secsign/Classes/"` makes no sense, 

change this to  `"Secsign\\Secsign\\": "Classes/"` and it should work

Comment: That is literally the line above that. I deleted the line you said was wrong, unistalled the extension flushed all caches and installed the extension again and it still gives me the exact same error message.

Comment: Try to dump the autoloader information `composer dump-autoload` or see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Autoloading/Index.html for further troubleshooting

Comment: Unfortunately that also does not do the trick. Do you know which method or class is throwing this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 Ways how you can solve this:

## 1. Load your Extension via the project composer.json

Create a folder for your custom Extensions, I named it here `Extensions` and move all your custom Extensions into this folder. Your `public/typo3conf/ext/` folder should now hold only Extensions loaded by composer and can be cleared at any time since a simple `composer i` will bring all Extensions back.

```
└── projectRoot
    ├── Extensions
    │   └── secsign
    │       └── Classes
    ├── composer.json
    └── public
        └── typo3conf
            └── ext
                └── secsign(symlink_by_composer)
```

**Add this to your project composer.json:**

```
  "repositories": {
    "0": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
    },
    "1": {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "./Extensions/*",
      "options": {
        "symlink": true
      }
    }
  },

  ...

  "require": {
    "secsign/secsign": "*",
    ...
  },
```

Remove the second line from the autoload in your Extensions composer.json

**public/Extensions/secsign/composer.json:**

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Secsign\\Secsign\\": "Classes/"
    }
  },
```

Now composer loads your project composer.json, finds your Extension, symlinks it into typo3conf/ext/ and reads your extensions composer.json and executes it.

**Loading all Ext into your project:** When your done with all this changes, just do a `composer update`. This will load all your third party extensions into `projectRoot/public/typo3conf/ext/` and symlink your custom extensions from `secsign -> ../../../Extensions/secsign`

**Adding more custom Extensions:** Just add your custom extension into `Extension/`, make sure it has a valid `composer.json` and include it with

```sh
composer req secsign/one-more-ext
```

## 2. Add your Classes to your project composer.json

Leave your Extension where it is, don't care about your extensions composer.json and
just add your Classes to your project composer.json:

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Secsign\\Secsign\\": "htdocs/typo3conf/ext/secsign/Classes/"
    }
  },
```

Now composer autoloads the classes from your projects composer.json, your Extensions composer.json is not even executed.

## Final

2. seems to be easier, but there are several reasons to go for 1.

Comment: At the moment the repositories part of my projects composer.json looks like this: ` "repositories": [
  
  { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
  
 ], ` how would I add the repositories statement you mentioned? I cannot seem to figure it out. Also once that is done how to I load the extension into TYPO3?

Comment: @droemmelbert I added the typo3.org repo to the example above. Also I added how  one more step to 1.

Comment: I actually did. Loading it via the composer.json did the trick. Thanks!