# “Controller does not exist. Reflection failed.” TYPO3 v2

Tags: reflection, controller, typo3

I have a typo3 extension (created with extension manager) and it seems no matter what I try I always get the following error:

```
Class CM\Parser\Controller\ParserController does not exist. Reflection failed.
```

I used the explanations for this problem [TYPO3 tutorial extension, controller does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133409/typo3-tutorial-extension-controller-does-not-exist) and ["Controller does not exist. Reflection failed." TYPO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376814/controller-does-not-exist-reflection-failed-typo3). Neither of them seem to work.
My composer.json in the root directory has the following entry:

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
    "CM\\parser\\": "./packages/cm-parser/Classes"
    }
}
```

My typo3conf/ext folder has a symlink on packages/cm-parser. My composer.json inside the extension directory (packages/cm-parser) has the entry:

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "CM\\parser\\": "./Classes"
    }
   }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

My directory structure looks like this (starting in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my-new-project) which is a typo3 v9.5 installation

```
    > .
    ├── packages
    │   └── cm-parser
    │       ├── Classes
    │       ├── Configuration
    │       ├── Documentation.tmpl
    │       ├── Resources
    │       └── Tests
    ├── public
    │   ├── fileadmin
    │   │   ├── _processed_
    │   │   ├── _temp_
    │   │   └── user_upload
    │   ├── typo3
    │   │   └── sysext
    │   ├── typo3conf
    │   │   ├── ext
    │   │   └── l10n
    │   ├── typo3temp
    │   │   ├── assets
    │   │   └── var
    │   └── uploads
    │       └── tx_extensionbuilder
    ├── var
    ...
```

In my typo3conf/ext directory there is a symlink called parser to packages/cm-parser (I think the composer created that for me).
So I hope this symlink works for Typo3. 
The files ext_emconf.php and ext_localconf.php are also in the right place. The folder structure above only displays my folders (tree -L 3) up to the third level.

Comment: the .Classes or ./packages won't work. Try to give the complete path to your classes, from the composer.json position.

Comment: I deleted the starting ./ but the relative paths are alright...?

Comment: i do not know how is your directory structure. You should take the absolute path from your composer.json to your extension classes. sth llike that: htdocs/typo3conf/ext/cm-parser/Classes  . But this is my directory structure. My composer.json is located in the same folder with htdocs, so i define the path from there

Comment: .
├── packages
│   └── cm-parser
│       ├── Classes
│       ├── Configuration
│       ├── Documentation.tmpl
│       ├── Resources
│       └── Tests
├── public
│   ├── fileadmin
│   │   ├── _processed_
│   │   ├── _temp_
│   │   └── user_upload
│   ├── typo3
│   │   └── sysext
│   ├── typo3conf
│   │   ├── ext
│   │   └── l10n
│   ├── typo3temp
│   │   ├── assets
│   │   └── var
│   └── uploads
│       └── tx_extensionbuilder
this is a part of my directory structure produced by tree starting in /opt/lampp/htdocs/my-new-project where my-new-project is a typo3 install

Comment: would you mind include the structure on your question, because it does not make any sense here :P .

Comment: sorry, done above

Comment: first of all you need to move your extension in the ext folder under public/typo3conf/ext . I dont know if it is intentional but your missing some key files like ext_emconf.php or ext_localconf.php as well. Then on your composer.json include on your psr (assuming that your composer is on the same folder with public and packages) "CM\\parser\\": "public//typo3conf/ext/cm-parser/Classes". After you re done, update the folder structure in your post.

Comment: If I follow your instructions I get an error parser already installed

Answer (score 2):

The controller class is `CM\Parser\Controller\ParserController`, while in your composer.json you're using `CM\\parser\\` (with a lowercase p) in the PSR4 autoload. This should be `CM\\Parser\\`

After changing this you need to of course run `composer dumpautoload` to reload the autoload information.

Comment: after correcting the small with a capital P in the extension composer.json and inserting the autoload too into the root composer.json with a capital P the extension wokrs fine. Thank you very much for all of your help

Answer (score 1):

In your **root** `composer.json` file:

➊ You do not need the PSR-4 autoload section for `"CM\\parser\\"`.
➋ You possibly have to add the path to `packages/*` as a **repository**.
➌ You have to include the composer namespace of your extension.

In your file system:

➍ You do not need `typo3conf/ext/` as a symbolic link to `packages/`.

Try the following changes:

In your root `composer.json` file, remove the PSR-4 autoload section as outlined above. Add the `packages/` directory as a path under `repositories`. For example:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "packages/*"
    }
  ],
 ...
}
```

Store your extension code in the following path: `packages/parser/`.

Assuming your extension key reads `parser` and your vendor name is `CM`, the composer namespace becomes `cm/parser`. Add this as a requirement to the composer config file. You can use the following command on the command line:

```sh
composer require cm/parser:dev-master
```

This assumes, that `packages/parser/` is a valid Git repository and has the `master` branch (do not use a version in the extension's `composer.json` file).

If the local Git repository and version (in the example above: `dev-master`) can be found, composer will automatically install all dependencies as required and it will create a symbolic link:

```sh
typo3conf/ext/parser -> ../../../packages/parser/
```

Also double check if all PHP files show the correct PHP namespace: `CM\Parser\...` and your controller class name reads `ParserController`.

If you can share your TYPO3 extension code, upload it to [GitHub](https://github.com) (or any other place) and share the link here. This way people can review your code and possibly spot further errors.

Comment: I've done all the steps above (I had to use :@dev at the composer require command and I had to rename my extension key from cm_parser to parser. At least my typo3 instance is working now.
I pushed my source code to https://github.com/christian2222/example2
the problem is that the Controller does not exist. Reflection failed. message remains as I open my frontend of my extension.